# Difference between CType(str,DateTime) and DateTime.Parse(str)

Tags: vb.net, string, datetime

I want to convert `str` into `DateTime`.

For that which option should I used in VB.NET? And Why?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to do it like this:

**Dates "disguised" as Object**

If I know the object is a datetime I use `CType`:

```
Dim table As New DataTable("Table")

table.Columns.Add("DATETIME_COLUMN", GetType(DateTime))
table.Rows.Add(Date.Now)
table.AcceptChanges()

Dim d As DateTime = CType(table.Rows(0).Item("DATETIME_COLUMN"), DateTime)
```

**Strings**

When dealing with strings I use `DateTime.Parse`. Notice that you can pass a cultureinfo.

```
Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("10.02.2014", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nb-NO"))
```

**Unknown/mixed types**

Finally, if I cannot be sure of the datatype, I use `Convert.ToDateTime`:

```
Dim d As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(obj, New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nb-NO"))
```

Answer (score 0):

> CType & CDate are VB.NET functions that have defined functionality.

```
Ctype('01/01/2014',DateTime)
```

> DateTime.Parse is a BCL (Base class library) method that has defined
>   functionality.

```
Dim value As String = "2000-02-02"
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(value)
```

Comment: @vingesh: I do know how to use these. And thank you for answer.

But my main question is still unanswered. "**WHICH ONE OF THESE I SHOULD USE? AND WHY?**"

Comment: you can use anything. if you are going for specially date then use datetime.parse

Answer (score 0):

As long as your string is in the right date format, you can just use CDate() function. This is the fastest and easiest way since you only have to type 7 characters excluding the string to be converted :) In terms of efficiency and speed, doesn't really make a difference.